# Add separate \maketitle to subfile which only executes when the subfile is compiled independently

Tags: titles, subfiles

I'm writing a document with multiple files, and I hope to add titles to them like so:

```
%%% main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\title{Main}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Some text
\subfile{a}
\end{document}
```

and

```
%%% a.tex
\documentclass[main]{subfiles}
\title{A}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Subordinate text
\end{document}
```

such that when I compile `main.tex`, `main.pdf` reads:

**Main**

Some text

Subordinate text

and when I complile `a.tex`, `a.pdf` reads:

**A**

Subordinate text

Is this possible? Thank you in advance!

Comment: The standard definition of `\maketitle` in `article` does `\global\let\author\relax`, so you could simply use `\ifx\author\relax\else\maketitle\fi`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subfiles package provides the `\ifSubfilesClassLoaded` macro which allows you to test if you compile the subfile or the main file:

```
%%% a.tex
\documentclass[main]{subfiles}
\title{A}
\begin{document}

\ifSubfilesClassLoaded{%
  \maketitle
}{}

Subordinate text
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think this is the intended method for this sort of operation, so I have marked this as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

One simple method you could use is to define an auxiliary in the preamble, since the preamble of the subfile will be ignored you can then use that auxiliary instead of `\maketitle`.

The following does this for your two files:

```
%%% main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\title{Main}
\newcommand\submaketitle{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Some text
\subfile{a}
\end{document}
```

```
%%% a.tex
\documentclass[main]{subfiles}
\title{A}
\newcommand\submaketitle{\maketitle}
\begin{document}
\submaketitle
Subordinate text
\end{document}
```

Then, if you compile `main.tex` you'll get:

[image: result of main.tex]

And if you compile `a.tex` you'll get:

[image: result of a.tex]

Comment: Extremely clever and exactly what I wanted, thank you!

Comment: Actually, shouldn't it be `\renewcommand\submaketitle{\maketitle}` in the second file?

Comment: @Canyon no, the preamble of the main file will not be used in the subfile it seems (else you would get an error for one of the `\newcommand`s, but I didn't for my tests...)